# Indent text after line break in itemize enviroment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, itemize, cv

I'm using the following [CV](https://www.overleaf.com/articles/quan-hos-cv/bwtrxfzzmnwr) as a template for my application. Everything works fine but there is one thing that i would like to change. For that consider the picture below:
[image]

I want to intend the letter **B** in the enumeration such that it stands directly under the letter **A** (same x - position). I tried using ~ or \vspace{0.1cm} to manually adjust the position of **B** but theses commands are not working in the enumeration-enviroment.

I created a minimal working example (which creates the picture above) from the template. Does someone know what i need to change to get my desired result?

**EDIT:**
I want only to indent the text in this specific enumeration-environment. The text in other enumeration-environment should not be indented!

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\reversemarginpar
\usepackage[paper=a4paper, marginparwidth=24mm, marginparsep=1mm, margin=15mm, includemp]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}


\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagestyle{empty}      % Uncomment this to get rid of page numbers
\fancyhf{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfootoffset{\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
\newlength{\footpageshift}
\setlength{\footpageshift}
          {0.1\textwidth+0.1\marginparsep+0.1\marginparwidth-2in}
\lfoot{\hspace{\footpageshift}%
       \parbox{3.5in}{\, \hfill %
                    \arabic{page} of \protect\pageref*{LastPage} % +LP
%                    \arabic{page}                               % -LP
                    \hfill \,}}

% Finally, give us PDF bookmarks
\usepackage{color,hyperref}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.3}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,
            linkcolor=darkblue,urlcolor=darkblue,
            anchorcolor=darkblue,citecolor=darkblue}

\newcommand{\makeheading}[1]%
        {\hspace*{-\marginparsep minus \marginparwidth}%
         \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep}%
                {\large \bfseries #1}\\[-0.15\baselineskip]%
                 \rule{\columnwidth}{1pt}%
         \end{minipage}}

\renewcommand{\section}[2]%
        {\pagebreak[2]\vspace{1\baselineskip}%
         \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
         \hspace{0in}%
         \marginpar{
         \raggedright \scshape #1}#2}

% An itemize-style list with lots of space between items
\newenvironment{outerlist}[1][\enskip\textbullet]%
        {\begin{itemize}[#1]}{\end{itemize}%
         \vspace{-0.6\baselineskip}}

% An environment IDENTICAL to outerlist that has better pre-list spacing
% when used as the first thing in a \section
\newenvironment{lonelist}[1][\enskip\textbullet]%
        {\vspace{-\baselineskip}\begin{list}{#1}{%
        \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%
        \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}}}
        {\end{list}\vspace{-.6\baselineskip}}

% An itemize-style list with little space between items
% \newenvironment{innerlist}[1][\enskip\textbullet]%
\newenvironment{innerlist}[1][\enskip$\circ$]%
        {\begin{compactitem}[#1]}{\end{compactitem}}

% An environment IDENTICAL to innerlist that has better pre-list spacing
% when used as the first thing in a \section
\newenvironment{loneinnerlist}[1][\enskip\textbullet]%
        {\vspace{-\baselineskip}\begin{compactitem}[#1]}
        {\end{compactitem}\vspace{-.6\baselineskip}}

% To add some paragraph space between lines.
% This also tells LaTeX to preferably break a page on one of these gaps
% if there is a needed pagebreak nearby.
\newcommand{\blankline}{\quad\pagebreak[2]}

% Uses hyperref to link DOI
\newcommand\doilink[1]{\href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{#1}}
\newcommand\doi[1]{doi:\doilink{#1}}

%\hyphenpenalty = 9999
\def\vs{\vspace{-0.1in}}
\begin{document}
% \makeheading{Curriculum Vitae\\ [0.3cm] TIEP HUU VU\quad~~~~~~\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad{\small Last update: December 17, 2015}}
\makeheading{\textbf{Bob}}


\section{Contact Information}

\newlength{\rcollength}\setlength{\rcollength}{3 in}
\vs
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\textwidth-\rcollength}p{\rcollength}}

 & Personal Information
\end{tabular}
%% ==============================================================
\vspace{0.2in}

\section{Education}
    \textbf{Physics, in Pseudo Science} \hfill October 2000 -- June 2020 
\begin{itemize}[label=-]
    \setlength\itemsep{0em}
    \item \textit{thesis:} A das das dkgsmpfsd fresfdnsjfdnf fsdfjlksdnfl rewlkrwe dasjk eajkasdad dawdsad eawedasf \vspace*{0.1cm}B
\end{itemize}

\section{some other section}
\begin{itemize}[label=-]
    \setlength\itemsep{0em}
    \item \textit{thesis:} items that contains a line break should not be intended in this enumeration-environment !!! 
    \item \textit{thesis:} items that contains a line break should not be intended in this enumeration-environment !!!  
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Will there be more items apart from the "thesis" item? If so, how will they be called and how would you like to align their texts?

Comment: Yes, in this enumeration environment there will be more items but they are much shorter and will not contain a line break. Other enumerations environment will contain a line break BUT i do not want to intend them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `tabularx` for this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\reversemarginpar
\usepackage[paper=a4paper, marginparwidth=24mm, marginparsep=1mm, margin=15mm, includemp]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}


\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagestyle{empty}      % Uncomment this to get rid of page numbers
\fancyhf{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfootoffset{\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
\newlength{\footpageshift}
\setlength{\footpageshift}
          {0.1\textwidth+0.1\marginparsep+0.1\marginparwidth-2in}
\lfoot{\hspace{\footpageshift}%
       \parbox{3.5in}{\, \hfill %
                    \arabic{page} of \protect\pageref*{LastPage} % +LP
%                    \arabic{page}                               % -LP
                    \hfill \,}}

% Finally, give us PDF bookmarks
\usepackage{color,hyperref}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.3}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,
            linkcolor=darkblue,urlcolor=darkblue,
            anchorcolor=darkblue,citecolor=darkblue}

\newcommand{\makeheading}[1]%
        {\hspace*{-\marginparsep minus \marginparwidth}%
         \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep}%
                {\large \bfseries #1}\\[-0.15\baselineskip]%
                 \rule{\columnwidth}{1pt}%
         \end{minipage}}

\renewcommand{\section}[2]%
        {\pagebreak[2]\vspace{1\baselineskip}%
         \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
         \hspace{0in}%
         \marginpar{
         \raggedright \scshape #1}#2}

% An itemize-style list with lots of space between items
\newenvironment{outerlist}[1][\enskip\textbullet]%
        {\begin{itemize}[#1]}{\end{itemize}%
         \vspace{-0.6\baselineskip}}

% An environment IDENTICAL to outerlist that has better pre-list spacing
% when used as the first thing in a \section
\newenvironment{lonelist}[1][\enskip\textbullet]%
        {\vspace{-\baselineskip}\begin{list}{#1}{%
        \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%
        \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}}}
        {\end{list}\vspace{-.6\baselineskip}}

% An itemize-style list with little space between items
% \newenvironment{innerlist}[1][\enskip\textbullet]%
\newenvironment{innerlist}[1][\enskip$\circ$]%
        {\begin{compactitem}[#1]}{\end{compactitem}}

% An environment IDENTICAL to innerlist that has better pre-list spacing
% when used as the first thing in a \section
\newenvironment{loneinnerlist}[1][\enskip\textbullet]%
        {\vspace{-\baselineskip}\begin{compactitem}[#1]}
        {\end{compactitem}\vspace{-.6\baselineskip}}

% To add some paragraph space between lines.
% This also tells LaTeX to preferably break a page on one of these gaps
% if there is a needed pagebreak nearby.
\newcommand{\blankline}{\quad\pagebreak[2]}

% Uses hyperref to link DOI
\newcommand\doilink[1]{\href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{#1}}
\newcommand\doi[1]{doi:\doilink{#1}}

%\hyphenpenalty = 9999
\def\vs{\vspace{-0.1in}}
\begin{document}
% \makeheading{Curriculum Vitae\\ [0.3cm] TIEP HUU VU\quad~~~~~~\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad{\small Last update: December 17, 2015}}
\makeheading{\textbf{Bob}}


\section{Contact Information}

\newlength{\rcollength}\setlength{\rcollength}{3 in}
\vs
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\textwidth-\rcollength}p{\rcollength}}

 & Personal Information
\end{tabular}
%% ==============================================================
\vspace{0.2in}

\section{Education}
    \textbf{Physics, in Pseudo Science} \hfill October 2000 -- June 2020 
\begin{itemize}[label=-]
    \setlength\itemsep{0em}
    \item \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[t]{@{}l@{~}X@{}} \textit{thesis:} &  B das das dkgsmpfsd fresfdnsjfdnf fsdfjlksdnfl rewlkrwe dasjk eajkasdad dawdsad  eaweda  B \end{tabularx}
    \item \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[t]{@{}l@{~}X@{}} \textit{some other item with long name:} &  B das das dkgsmpfsd fresfdnsjfdnf fsdfjlksdnfl rewlkrwe dasjk eajkasdad dawdsad  eaw B \end{tabularx}
        \item \textit{shorter item:} shorter item without line break
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked out!